# Logstash Grok get number field

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, grok

I use Grok filter in Logstash to break one long message into several fields.

The example Message: http://localhost:8080/MRLService/api/v1/reportNotes 11-24-2016 10:59:49 8ms country=AUS pesticide=ABA3000

filter: filter {
    grok {match => {"log4j2_message" => "%{URIPATH:url} %{DATESTAMP:startTime} %{NUMBER:timeTaken}ms %{GREEDYDATA:parameters}"}}
}

it is working fine except the timetaken (8) is string type instead of number type I supposed,

[image: mapping list]

Could anyone please tell how to make the timetaken field as number in Logstash?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last is the type

`{NUMBER:timeTaken:int}`

or just convert the filed to int or float (not suggest due to this will lower performance then the first method)

```
mutate {
   convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
}
```